# ContainerLaunchContext.setResource() missing of hadoop yarn

Tags: hadoop, hadoop-yarn

http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.1.0-beta/hadoop-yarn/hadoop-yarn-site/WritingYarnApplications.html

I am try to make the example work well from the above link.but I can't compile the code below

```
 Resource capability = Records.newRecord(Resource.class);
 capability.setMemory(512);
 amContainer.setResource(capability);

 // Set the container launch content into the
 // ApplicationSubmissionContext
 appContext.setAMContainerSpec(amContainer);
```

amContainer is ContainerLaunchContext and my hadoop version is 2.1.0-beta.
I did some investigation. I found there's no method "setResource" in  ContainerLaunchContext

I have 3 question about this 
1) the method has been removed or something? 
2) if the method has been removed, how can I do now? 
3) is there any doc about yarn, because I found the doc in website is very easy, I hope I can get a manual or something. for example,
capability.setMemory(512);
I don't know it's 512k or 512M according comments in code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set memory available to ApplicationMaster via commend. As such:

```
// Set the necessary command to execute the application master
Vector<CharSequence> vargs = new Vector<CharSequence>(30);
...
vargs.add("-Xmx" + amMemory + "m"); // notice "m" indicating megabytes, you can use also -Xms combined with -Xmx
... // transform vargs to String commands
amContainer.setCommands(commands);
```

This should solve your problem. As for the 3 questions. Yarn is rapidly evolving software. My advice forget documentation, get source code and read it. This will answer a lot of your questions.

Comment: `Resource capability = Records.newRecord(Resource.class);
capability.setMemory(amMemory);
appContext.setResource(capability); // ApplicationSubmissionContext`

try this

Comment: There is no function `setResource` for a `ContainerLaunchContext`.

Comment: Then try to use java arguments. as in the original answer. It works for 2.3.0 version.

Comment: I use 2.2.0. It did not work for me. However, I will update to 2.3.0 soon.

Answer (score 1):

This is actually proper solution to the question. Previous answer might cause incorrect execution !!!

@Dyin I couldn't fit it in the comment ;) Validated for 2.2.0 and 2.3.0

Driver setting up resources for AppMaster:

```
ApplicationSubmissionContext appContext = app.getApplicationSubmissionContext();
ApplicationId appId = appContext.getApplicationId();
appContext.setApplicationName(this.appName);

// Set up the container launch context for the application master
ContainerLaunchContext amContainer = Records.newRecord(ContainerLaunchContext.class);

Resource capability = Records.newRecord(Resource.class);
capability.setMemory(amMemory);        
appContext.setResource(capability);

appContext.setAMContainerSpec(amContainer);

Priority pri = Records.newRecord(Priority.class);
pri.setPriority(amPriority);
appContext.setPriority(pri);

appContext.setQueue(amQueue);

// Submit the application to the applications manager
yarnClient.submitApplication(appContext); // this.yarnClient = YarnClient.createYarnClient();
```

In ApplicationMaster this is how you should specify resources for containers (workers).

```
private AMRMClient.ContainerRequest setupContainerAskForRM() {
        // setup requirements for hosts
        // using * as any host will do for the distributed shell app
        // set the priority for the request
        Priority pri = Records.newRecord(Priority.class);
        pri.setPriority(requestPriority);

        // Set up resource type requirements
        // For now, only memory is supported so we set memory requirements
        Resource capability = Records.newRecord(Resource.class);
        capability.setMemory(containerMemory);

        AMRMClient.ContainerRequest request = new AMRMClient.ContainerRequest(capability, null, null,
                pri);
        return request;
    }
```

Some run() or main() method in your AppMaster

```
AMRMClientAsync.CallbackHandler allocListener = new RMCallbackHandler();
resourceManager = AMRMClientAsync.createAMRMClientAsync(1000, allocListener);
resourceManager.init(conf);
resourceManager.start();

for (int i = 0; i < numTotalContainers; ++i) {
  AMRMClient.ContainerRequest containerAsk = setupContainerAskForRM();
  resourceManager.addContainerRequest(containerAsk); // 
}
```

Launching containers
You can use the original answer solution (java cmd), but it's just a cherry on top. It should work anyway.